# Placed on + only date (not time)

Tags: comments, content, date-time, timestamp

When I create a comment or, ... you can set **Placed on**. 
For example: `20 june, 2014 on 14:23` .

But I don't want the time (14:23). Only `20 june, 2014`.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I do this?

**Some clarification:**

So when I edit my blog post I want to adjust the time it was posted. Like this:

[image]

As you can see you can enter the time after the `@` sign. But I don't want to give in the time, only the date. Is this possible?

Comment: Would you explain more where exactly you want to have date only?

Comment: Edit your `comments.php` and do the tweak there. That template is responsible for displaying the comment time.

Comment: I've updated my topic. Isn't there another way than adjusting the code?